# How do I pass ParseResults to other methods?

Tags: scala, types, parameters, parser-combinators

```
void whatever() {
  // ...
  val parser = new MyParser
  val parse = parser.parse(input)
  if (parse successful) {
    semanticAnalysis(parse)
  }
}

void semanticAnalysis(parse: DontKnowTheCorrectType) {
  // ...
}
```

What type do I have to give to the formal parameter `parse`? Hovering over `parse` inside `whatever` says `val parse: parser.ParseResult[parsing.Program]`, but of course that doesn't work as a parameter type of `semanticAnalysis`, because the local variable `parse` is not in scope there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parse results are path-dependent types because they are results of this specific parser and there's no guarantee they are compatible.

This is why parsers are usually not instantiated the way you use them (`new MyParser`), but as `object`.

```
object MyParser extends RegexParsers { 
   def statements : Parser[List[Statement]] = // ...
} 

def handleResult(res: MyParser.ParseResult[List[Statement]]) = { // ... } 

val res = MyParser.parseAll(MyParser.statements, "/* */")
```

If you need more dynamic behaviour (or want concurrent parsing, [parser combinators aren't thread-safe](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4929), ouch), you'll just have to keep the parser object accessible (and stable) wherever you want to use its results.

Sadly, passing a parser and its result around together is not trivial because you run into the prohibition of dependent method types, e.g.

```
  def fun(p: scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers, res: p.ParseResult[_]) = {}
```

won't compile ("illegal dependent method type"), but there are ways to get around that if you must, like the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769503/returning-a-path-dependent-type).

Comment: That's gonna be a problem, because I put some state into my parser... I know, that's not purely functional, and I will probably burn in hell for that :)

Comment: Can you not do `def fun(p: scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers)(res: p.ParseResult[_]) = {}`?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to define `semanticAnalysis` as:

```
def semanticAnalysis(parse: MyParser#ParseResult[parsing.Program]) = {
  ...
}
```

Note the use of `#` instead of `.` for the type. There are more details [about type projections here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676048/why-does-one-select-scala-type-members-with-a-hash-instead-of-a-dot), but basically, `parser.ParseResult` is different for each `parser`, while `MyParser#ParseResult` is the same for all `parser` instances.

But, as [themel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/334485/themel) says, you should probably be using `object` instead of `class`.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite it like this:

```
def whatever() {
  // ...
  val parser = new MyParser
  def semanticAnalysis(parse: parser.ParseResult) {
    // ...
  }
  val parse = parser.parse(input)
  if (parse successful) {
    semanticAnalysis(parse)
  }
}
```

If you have this being called from multiple places, then maybe this:

```
  class SemanticAnalysis(parser: Parser) {
    def apply(parse: parser.ParseResult) {
      // ...
    }
  }
```

And then

```
  if (parse successful) {
    new SemanticAnalysis(parser)(parse)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

When I need to use the result of parser combinators in other parts of a program, I extract the success result or error message from the path-dependent `ParseResult` and put the data into an independent type.  It's more verbose than I like, but I want to keep the combinator instance an implementation detail of the parser.

```
sealed abstract class Result[+T]
case class Success[T](result: T) extends Result[T]
case class Failure(msg: String) extends Result[Nothing]
case class Error(msg: String) extends Result[Nothing]

/** Parse the package declarations in the file. */
def parse(file: String): Result[List[Package]] = {
  val stream = ... // open the file...
  val parser = new MyParser
  val result = parser.parseAll(parser.packages, stream)   
  stream.close()
  result match {
    case parser.Success(packages, _) => Success(packages)
    case parser.Failure(msg, _) => Failure(msg)
    case parser.Error(msg, _) => Error(msg)
  }
}
```